# Getting low FPS while using x11grab ffmpeg

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ffmpeg

Question : Why I am getting ~7 FPS even I have specified 30 ?

I am using raspberry pi 3 and compiled latest soruce code from the GIT and still getting low fps(~7) while using below ffmpeg command using x11grab.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1280,720 -i :0.0+0,0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -g 30 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -ar 44100 -threads 0 -bufsize 5048k -f flv file.flv
```

I have tried working with `-threads` , `-bufsize` , replaced `-r 30` with `-framerate` option still no luck and my CPU usage is ~40%

below is my output :

```
  ffmpeg version N-92829-g1a6cca1989 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libxcb
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
[x11grab @ 0x1ffe270] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #1, x11grab, from ':0.0+0,0':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 30 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x20076d0] VBV maxrate unspecified, assuming CBR
[libx264 @ 0x20076d0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x20076d0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x20076d0] 264 - core 157 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=30 keyint_min=3 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=cbr mbtree=0 bitrate=2000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=2000 vbv_bufsize=5048 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'a.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.42.104 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 5048000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.42.104 aac
[x11grab @ 0x1ffe270] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    8 fps=7.2 q=19.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=3520.0kbits/s speed=0.000899x    
frame=   12 fps=7.4 q=27.0 size=      92kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=4647.7kbits/s speed=0.0993x    
frame=   16 fps=7.4 q=22.0 size=     122kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=3318.1kbits/s speed=0.14x    
frame=   20 fps=7.5 q=20.0 size=     130kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=2556.7kbits/s speed=0.156x    
frame=   24 fps=7.5 q=20.0 size=     164kB time=00:00:00.55 bitrate=2419.0kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=   28 fps=7.5 q=19.0 size=     181kB time=00:00:00.69 bitrate=2132.1kbits/s speed=0.188x    
frame=   32 fps=7.6 q=18.0 size=     184kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate=1800.3kbits/s speed=0.198x    
frame=   36 fps=7.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=     351kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=2464.6kbits/s speed=0.244x
```

**UPDATE:** Today I have tried latest code and compiled it but still no luck

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Why I am getting ~7 FPS even I have specified 30 ? even I have compiled latest source code from the repository.